# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent relationship leftjoin ON complicated

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, relational-database, left-join, eloquent

**Mysql Query**

```
    LEFT JOIN matches as m
    ON sched.league_id = m.leagueid
    AND sched.starttime >= m.start_time
    AND (sched.team_a_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_b_id = m.dire_team_id)
    OR (sched.team_b_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_a_id = m.dire_team_id)
```

**Laravel Eloquent**

```
    ->leftJoin('matches as m', function($join){
        $join->on('league_id','=','m.leagueid');
        $join->on('starttime','=','m.start_time');
        // @TODO  AND (sched.team_a_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_b_id = m.dire_team_id)
        // @TODO OR (sched.team_b_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_a_id = m.dire_team_id)
    })
```

**Question**

- How to left join on 
  *(something = something AND something = something) OR(something = something AND something = something)* using Laravel Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
             $join->on('league_id','=','m.leagueid')
             ->on('starttime','<=','m.start_time')
             ->on(DB::raw('m.radiant_team_id'), 'IN', DB::raw('(team_a_id,team_b_id)'))
             ->on(DB::raw('m.dire_team_id'), 'IN', DB::raw('(team_a_id,team_b_id)'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL query is wrong in the first place, I'm sure this is what you wanted:

```
LEFT JOIN matches as m
ON sched.league_id = m.leagueid
AND sched.starttime >= m.start_time
AND (
  sched.team_a_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_b_id = m.dire_team_id
  OR sched.team_b_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_a_id = m.dire_team_id
)
```

Now, unfortunately Laravel is not capable of building this join.

So the only way is this:

```
->leftJoin('matches as m', function ($j) {
   $j->on('league_id','=','m.leagueid')
     ->on('starttime','=','m.start_time')
     ->on(sched.team_a_id = m.radiant_team_id)
     ->on(sched.team_b_id = m.dire_team_id)
     ->orOn('league_id','=','m.leagueid')
     ->on('starttime','=','m.start_time')
     ->on(sched.team_b_id = m.radiant_team_id)
     ->on(sched.team_a_id = m.dire_team_id);
})
```

or playing with raw statements (pay attention to parentheses within `DB::raw`):

```
->leftJoin('matches as m', function ($j) {
   $j->on('league_id','=','m.leagueid')
    ->on('starttime','=','m.start_time')
    ->on(
     DB::raw( '(sched.team_a_id',
     '=', 
     DB::raw('m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_b_id = m.start_time'
  .'OR sched.team_b_id = m.radiant_team_id AND sched.team_a_id = m.start_time)')
    );
})
```

Comment: Your t he best MAN! :D please let me know if the laravel has updated this :D

Comment: Current dev-master provides no change, feel free to create a PR :)